# How can i make my circle react with the whole rectangle?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want `this.r` (the circle), to react to the whole area of the rectangle (`other`), `if di < this.r`, however, it only reacts to the top left corner of the rectangle, because that is where the x and y points/coordinates are (`other.x` and `other.y`).

```py
intersects(other){
    let di =  dist(this.x, this.y, other.x, other.y)
    if (di < this.r) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can i make the "dist" function cover the whole area of the rectangle, not only the top left corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dist()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/dist) calculates the distance between two points.
A rectangle has 4 corner points. In your case the points are (0, 0), (`other.x`, 0), (0, `other.y`) and (`other.x`, `other.y`).

But, to verify if the circle "leaves" the rectangular area, you don't need `dist()` at all. You've to verify if the circle is out at 1 of the 4 sides of the rectangle:

```js
intersects(other_x, other_y){#
    let is_out = this.x - this.r < 0       || // out at the left
                 this.x + this.r > other_x || // out at the right
                 this.y - this.r < 0       || // out at the top
                 this.y + this.r > other_y;   // out at the bottom  
    return is_out
```